# Alternative to Permissive rails gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Anyone know alternatives to Permissive? Or other gems that compare in terms of features?

Comment: To be more specific, I'm looking for a model-based permissions system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer **declarative_authorization** over cancan, **if the user's roles are more complex**

https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization

http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization

http://steffenbartsch.com/blog/2008/09/delclarative-authorization/

---

With `declarative_authorization` you can define role-based authorization of your models and methods.

You can define permissions on models, and the methods in a model.  You can further limit permissions if certain conditions are met, e.g. you can specify certain permissions are applied only if a certain attribute of the object has a certain value.

Here's an example, which specifies that  a regular user can only read and modify accounts of companies where s/he is employed_at (assuming that the accounts are arranged in a tree-like fashion, e.g. with "ancestry" gem)

```
authorization do 
 role :user do
    # ...
    has_permission_on :accounts , :to => [:index, :show, :edit, :update] do
      if_attribute :id => is_in { user.employed_at_account.subtree_ids }
    end
    # ...
  end

  role :admin do
    # ...
    has_permission_on :accounts , :to => [:create, :new, :index, :show , :edit, :update  ]
    # ...
  end   
end
```

Comment: I've taken a look at declarative authorization. It does not seem to be able to apply permissions on an instance of a model? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just curious, why do you prefer declarative_authorization over CanCan? It seems that most of the Rails community has adapted CanCan as the number one authorization gem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it qualifies as 'model-based', but have you looked at CanCan?:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Edit:

Cancan has been discontinued (unofficially) and a contributor created a new project called Cancancan.

https://github.com/bryanrite/cancancan